# Calculating Postage using IIF issue Issue

Tags: ms-access, calculated-columns, iif

I need a little push in the right direction. I'm attempting to calculate postage given specific postage costs. The formula I'm using currently is as follows:

`Postage: IIF([Field15]<15,"5.95",IIF(AND([Field15]>15,[Field15]<30),"9.95",IIF(AND([Field15]>30,[Field15]<50),"12.95",IIF(AND([Field15]>50,[Field15]<75),"16.95",IIF(AND([Field15]>75,[Field15]<100),"18.95",IIF(AND([Field15]>100,[Field15]<150),"21.95",IIF(AND([Field15]>150,[Field15]<200),"26.95",IIF(AND([Field15]>200,[Field15]<250),"29.95",[Field15]*0.12))))))))`

I know i'm close but not sure what I'm missing to make this work. It keeps telling me invalid syntax but not sure where the problem is.  Any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't do `IIF(AND(`. I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but you probably should use `SWITCH` instead of loads of `IIF` statements. You probably should use `[Field15]>15 AND [Field15]<30` instead of `AND([Field15]>15,[Field15]<30)`

Comment: Have a look at the `Switch` function: https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/switch.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should look somethig like this:

```
Postage: SWITCH([Field15]<15,"5.95",[Field15]<30,"9.95",[Field15]<50,"12.95",....)
```

The VBA Switch function evaluates a list of Boolean expressions and returns a value associated with the first true expression.

Comment: Thanks for the help. what I'm trying to do is have this calculate the postage cost automatically based on a retail price range. so for example anything higher that 15 in field 15 would show a shipping cost of 9.95 and so up, going up by price.  I'm attempting to use your formula suggestion but getting a syntax error still. I'll post below what I have for code

Comment: `SWITCH([Field15]>15,"5.95",[Field15]<15,"9.95",[Field15]<30,"12.95",[Field15]<50,"16.95",[Field15]<75,"18.95",[Field15]<100,"21.95",[field15]<150,"26.95",[Field15]<200,"29.95")`

Comment: Okay I've got it working sorta. but It wont' go above recognizing any postage set above 15... so if a retail is 30 or above it still shows the 9.95 amount instead of what it should be...

Comment: Found the issue. I had to go from highest number to lowest. That corrected the issues I was having.